# How to get the current parent directory in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

how will I get the current parent directory in htaccess? I'm working on redirecting the page when error 404 is found... Here is my code...

```
ErrorDocument 404 /sitewylog/www/404-redirect.php
```

but when the directory changes like, /sitewylog/www/404-redirect.php turns to /some-new-name/www/404-redirect.php because someone pulled my copy to a different folder name (eg. using RapidSVN).. It produces an error that says, 404.html not found.. because the 404-redirect.php contains this code...

```
<?php

include_once '../config.php';

header('Location: /'.ROOT.'/www/404.html');
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Just use `/www/404-redirect.php`, the path is already relative to your document root, see [ErrorDocument](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#errordocument)

Comment: I already tried that, but still, causing an error.

Comment: What is the message in Apache's error log file?

Comment: [Fri Jun 03 15:52:04.431488 2016] [:error] [pid 5984:tid 1600] [client ::1:61666] script 'C:/xampp/htdocs/SiteWylog/www/pages(fr)/dssad.php' not found or unable to stat

Comment: In the browser, it says...

Not Found

The requested URL /SiteWylog/www/pages(fr)/dsad.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Maybe `DocumentRoot` isn't pointing to `/sitewylog`.

Comment: Yes, I suspect that too, how will make it pointed? I look tried editing the httpd.conf but it seems does not work.

Comment: It depends on how your configuration files are structured. On a Ubuntu system, the sites are located in `.../sites-available` and `.../sites-enabled`.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your time. I'll try to figure it out next time.